# Table View Cell with a Textfield

Tags: ios, uitableview, delegates, textfield

I have a subclass, CustomCell, which inherits from my parent class, CreateEvent. The subclass describes the individual cells for the table view cell, which is on the CreateEvent View controller. In one specific cell, I have a textfield, that is linked to the CustomCell file, but I am having trouble getting the value from that textfield when a user enters into the textfield. I am also having trouble dismissing the keyboard with outside touches and pressing the return key, but I am primarily focused on getting the text from the textfield. I am familiar with doing these functionalities on a normal swift file but because this is a subclass, I'm not sure what to do. What I've tried is to use:

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var entranceFeeTextField: UITextField!

override func awakeFromNib() {
     super.awakeFromNib()

}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
     super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
}
```

And:

```
class CreateEventVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, CustomCellDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let currentCellDescriptor = getCellDescriptorForIndexPath(indexPath)
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: currentCellDescriptor["cellIdentifier"] as! String, for: indexPath) as! CustomCell


    cell.entranceFeeTextField.delegate = self

    entranceFeeAmount = cell.entranceFeeTextField.text!
}
```

This code doesn't run and I'm not exactly sure which textfield delegates I need to run in order to be able to get the Text value from the textfield.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `UITextFieldDelegate` methods [textFieldShouldEndEditing(*:)*](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitextfielddelegate/1619592-textfieldshouldendediting) or [textFieldShouldReturn(:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitextfielddelegate/1619603-textfieldshouldreturn) to get the results of the textfield.

for example:

```
func textFieldShouldEndEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    print("TextField should end editing method called")
    let textFromCell = textField.text!
    //do whatever you want with the text!
    return true;
}
```

In this code snippet, `textField` will actually be your instance of `entranceFeeTextField`. Because somewhere, when that textfield stops editing, it calls `self.delegate?.textFieldShouldEndEditing(entranceFeeTextField)` and that method's **implementation** is inside your `CreateEventVC`.

Returning `true` will allow the textfield to end editing. This method will only get called when the user wants to stop editing. So you should remove `entranceFeeAmount = cell.entranceFeeTextField.text!` from your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method because that's where you create your cell. At that point a user will not have typed into your textfield, so no use in getting the text from it as soon as it has been made.

All you have to do is implement one of those methods in `CreateEventVC`.

Comment: This is very helpful. It makes sense that I need to tell the textfield to stop editing to be able to pull the value. However, in the line "let textFromCell = textField.text!", it won't recognize the textField from the CustomCell file.

Comment: @Kevin if you set the delegate properly, and implement that method in your `CreateEventVC`, yes it will. The parameter to the method says `textField`, but that is just the textField being passed by the delegate. When it gets called it will be your `entranceFeeTextField`. Unless you mean something else?

Comment: I did use entranceFeeTextField. It must be the delegate that I am conforming too properly. Is it not 'cell.entranceFeeTextField.delegate = self'? What else do I need to use to satisfy the delegate? Thanks

Comment: Put a breakpoint in the method. See if it is ever getting called. Try one of the other UITextField methods

Comment: I just get the error, "Use of unresolved identifier 'entranceFieldTextField' ". I was able to set the textfield delegate to self in the cellForRowAtIndexPath, but I'm not sure how to get the textFieldShouldEndEditing function to communicate with that delegate to recognize the entranceFeeTextField

Comment: @Kevin I edited my answer. Please don't add your own code to that snippet. It will work as-is. Do not reference your subclass in that method. Only use the `textField` that is passed into that method via the `UITextFieldDelegate`

Answer (score 1):

```
Here is the full code: (Xcode 8 swift 3)
(View Controller Class) 

class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate,UITextFieldDelegate
{
    @IBOutlet weak var tbl: UITableView!
    var cell = TableViewCell()
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
         cell = tbl.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CELL") as! TableViewCell
        cell.configure(text: "", placeholder: "EnterText")
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return 1
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int
    {
        return 1
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool
    {


       print( cell.returnTextOfTextField() )
        print(cell.txtField.text)
        cell.txtField .resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }

}


TableViewCell class (Custom cell):
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell,UITextFieldDelegate
{

    @IBOutlet weak var txtField: UITextField!
    override func awakeFromNib()
    {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }
    public func configure(text: String?, placeholder: String) {
        txtField.text = text
        txtField.placeholder = placeholder

        txtField.accessibilityValue = text
        txtField.accessibilityLabel = placeholder
    }

    func returnTextOfTextField() -> String
    {
        print(txtField.text)
       return txtField.text!
    }
    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool)
    {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}


"CELL" is the identifier given to cell in Nib .
```

Comment: When I run my code: cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "entranceFee") as! CustomCell, where entranceFee is my .xib file that contains the textfield, the compiler complains about  'fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value'

Comment: Please refer the link you will find the code : 
https://github.com/shemona-ios/stack

Answer (score 0):

This is working code , I get the value from text field and even keyboard is resigned.

```
var cell = TableViewCell() // customCell
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
         cell = tbl.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CELL") as! TableViewCell
        cell.configure(text: "", placeholder: "EnterText")
        return cell
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return 1
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int
{
    return 1
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool
{
     //cell = tbl.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CELL") as! TableViewCell


   print( cell.returnTextOfTextField() )
    print(cell.txtField.text)
    cell.txtField .resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}




/// Custom cell class


class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell,UITextFieldDelegate
{

@IBOutlet weak var txtField: UITextField!
override func awakeFromNib()
{
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}
public func configure(text: String?, placeholder: String) {
    txtField.text = text
    txtField.placeholder = placeholder

    txtField.accessibilityValue = text
    txtField.accessibilityLabel = placeholder
}

func returnTextOfTextField() -> String
{
    print(txtField.text)
   return txtField.text!
}
override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool)
{
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
```

}

Comment: I am having trouble with the code 'cell = tbl.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CELL") as! TableViewCell cell.configure(text: "", placeholder: "EnterText") return cell }'. There are many errors that pop up. I am not sure what the withIdentifier: "CELL" is alluding to as well as the placeholder: "EnterText" is.

Comment: please add a snapshot of the same . TableViewCell  is the class for custom cell . Or what i can do is send you the code . Add you mail id will post the code.